# APNs works fine separate from Firebase, but cannot get notifications to work in FCM

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I am setting up Firebase with APNs for the first time. I am working in Swift with an iOS app and I have apns messages working separately without Firebase -- so remote push notifications are received on the device in background and while running app. I can use this tool https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher to send notifications on Sandbox and Production apns certs successfully by sending this json blob as an example:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testing","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}
```

However, now I am trying to incorporate Firebase and not getting the same behavior on the iOS device.

I have Firebase messaging setup and the app prints remote messages with `"shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true"` but APNs is never received (with this set to false then device doesn't print anything). No push notifications are received on device. I don't believe APNs is being mapped correctly for Firebase messages as I cannot get the device to display push notifications in the same way that I can with NWPusher on strictly APNs Sandbox and Production certs. Firebase app console has the app's .p12 apns cert (which is working fine for apns without firebase involved)

Here's a sample request I try to send to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
    "to" : "eqkeyhereinifnbe",
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "data" : {
        "body" : "Notification",
        "title": "testing",
        "key_1" : "Data for key one",
        "key_2" : "Hello Meowww", 
    }
}
```

API returns a success response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 634054476369,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:15329261441bfd36cccfb49c"
        }
    ]
}
```

In iOS app's AppDelegate:

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
     print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)!")
     }
```

^prints the message successfully from the api on device:

> Received data message: [AnyHashable("collapse_key"): type_a,
>   AnyHashable("key_1"): Data for key one, AnyHashable("from"): 9861340,
>   AnyHashable("key_2"): Hello Meowww, AnyHashable("body"): Notification,
>   AnyHashable("title"): testing]!

However this received message doesn't do any of the APNs notification magic to an iOS device. I tried to send the same json blob to Firebase API that works fine in NWPusher: `{"aps":{"alert":"Testing","badge":1,"sound":"default"}}`, but device does not display the notification. Why? How troubleshoot this to make Firebase send the same APNs notification to show notifications on device?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to write the request with "message" and "data" objects like this:

```
{
    "to" : "aTokenHerefonsfondfodnfdofndf",
    "collapse_key" : "type_a",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Notification title test",
      "body":"It worked body"
    },
    "data" : {
        "body" : "Notification",
        "title": "testing",
        "key_1" : "Data for key 1",
        "key_2" : "Hello Meowww"
    }
}
```